# Recovering from postgresql password change in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In testing subscriptions within postgresql, there came a realisation that spaces in passwords were not going to be digested properly.  Thus with postgresql commands a role was edited `ALTER ROLE deploy WITH PASSWORD '4rut9_qo38';` *fictitious pwd*
However, from that moment on, an application was responding with:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "deploy"
```

Now the password is not defined in the application and

```
bundle exec rails c
Rails.application.credentials.config
{:telegram=>{:bot=>{:token=>"49202[...]
```

yields no password credential and, noteworthy, no secret_key_base.
`pg_hba.conf` remains in its default state with an added line for replication purposes

```
local   all             postgres                                md5
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             10.935.0.18/32           md5
```

There was an attempt to set the connection via `database.yml` by adding the password line

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: example_development
  password: '4rut9_qo38'
```

The password in postgresql (v12) was reset to the previous value `ALTER ROLE deploy WITH PASSWORD '4rut9 qo38';`,
`sudo service nginx restart`, `sudo service postgresql restart` and `touch tmp/restart.txt` to relaunch the app, but to no avail:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "deploy"
```

The real curiosity arises from a second app on the same server: it **IS** connecting appropriately, `credentials.config` has a secret_key_base and `database.yml` has no password inserted.

Further oddities: one can change the user password via postgresql, add the password to `database.yml` to the same value and the behaviours of both applications remains unaltered - thereby excluding issues with `pg_hba.conf`...

Clearly the first app is not well configured (both are rails 6.1.3).

How should the passwords be set in a failsafe manner, assuming that the password of the postgresql `deploy` user has to change, so that each of these applications runs as expected?

Answer (score 0):

`/home/deploy/example/.rbenv-vars` needs to be checked; it contains the database connection password.

This can be reset, or given the replication case above, the postgresql role can be amended accordingly.